# How can i replace VBA manual change to automate(or input box)?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace !R46C181 to !R46C182, etc. Everytime i launch my macros, since it will take new column(month)

Right now , every month i manually change via find/replace (181 to 182) to move it to the next month before launching my macros.

Is there a way to put some - Input box? Like i where i just place 182, and it will update everything to it

Here is the part of that code

```
 Range("BD31").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=SUM('[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!R46C181)"
Range("BD32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=SUM('[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!R47C181:R49C181)"
Range("BD33").Select
```

And here is full code:

```
Sub Auto_ship()

'

' Auto_ship Macro

'

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l

'

Range("BD31").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _

"=SUM('[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!R46C181)"

Range("BD32").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _

"=SUM('[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!R47C181:R49C181)"

Range("BD33").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _

"=SUM('[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!R50C181)"

Range("BD34").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _

"=SUM('[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!R51C181:R52C181)"

Range("BC31").Select

Selection.Copy

Range("BD31:BD35").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _

SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("BD31:BD34").Select

Selection.Copy

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _

:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("BG25").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("BC30").Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BC30:BD30"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("BC30:BD30").Select

Range("BB3:BC3").Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BB3:BD3"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("BB3:BD3").Select

Range("BD3").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "'Sep 2020"

Range("BE3").Select

Columns("BC:BC").EntireColumn.AutoFit

ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a

```
Dim month As String
month =InputBox("My Month")
```

save it to a string and then concat with  `&` eg
`"=SUM('[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!R46C"& month`

of cause better ways to do this,error check etc, just a quick one here

Comment: Hello! thanks for reply! I posted full code , can you please take a look and help where can i put ur part of code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution below features and InputBox where you can enter a column either by number (like 182) or by its alphabetic ID (like "FZ"). The specified column will then be used to create the formulas your code needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Auto_ship()
    ' 102
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l

    ' include apostrophes and exclamation point in the string:-
    Const Source    As String = "'[sales.xlsm]Market Share'!"
    
    Dim C           As Variant          ' target column
    
    C = InputBox("Enter a column ID (Number or letter):", _
                 "Target column", "FA")
    If Len(C) = 0 Then Exit Sub         ' blank to exit
    
    If Not IsNumeric(C) Then C = Columns(C).Column
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
    
    Cells(31, "BD").Formula = "=SUM(" & Source & RangeName(C, 46) & ")"
    Cells(32, "BD").Formula = "=SUM(" & Source & RangeName(C, 47, 49) & ")"
    Cells(33, "BD").Formula = "=SUM(" & Source & RangeName(C, 50) & ")"
    Cells(34, "BD").Formula = "=SUM(" & Source & RangeName(C, 51, 52) & ")"
    
    Cells(31, "BD").Copy                ' copy the formats from BD31 to Bd32:Bd35
    Range("BD32:BD35").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    ' if you want the formatsd to be copied to the current column use this line instead:-
'    Range(Cells(32, C), Cells(35, C)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    ' why would you copy the values from BD31:BD34 to that same address ?????
'    Range("BD31:BD34").Copy             ' copy the values
'    Range("BD31:BD34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
'    Range("BG25").Select                ' what's the purpose of this serlection?

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Private Function RangeName(ByVal C As Long, _
                           ByVal Rstart As Long, _
                           Optional ByVal Rend As Long)
    ' 102
    
    Dim Rng         As Range
    
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(Rstart, C), Cells(IIf(Rend, Rend, Rstart), C))
    RangeName = Rng.Address
End Function
```

The exact range address is created by the function `RangeName` which takes 2 or 3 arguments: the column, the start row and the end row. The latter can be omitted if you want to specify a single cell. I use A1 notations instead of R1C1. That's a matter of preference in this case.

My code looks radically different from yours because I removing all `Select` statements. They serve no useful purpose. Excel knows perfectly well where its cells are once you tell it the coordinates.

The second half of your code didn't make sense to me. I couldn't fathom why you would want to copy BD31:BD34 to Bd31:Bd34 every month. I gave one example how you might use the column you enter to address different cells each month directly. For the rest of the code I urge you to continue removing all `Select` statements and just address each range directly as you instruct what is to be done with it.